# Is Siri good for practicing Chinese pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation, software

Is Siri really that good for Chinese pronunciation? I mean, there will be nothing like a native speaker.

For example, when I say "Ní haô" or "Wò qù", it still says the expected characters.

If Siri is not that good, is there something better perhaps?

Comment: Please see [Can Siri be used for foreign-language speaking and listening practice?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/4528) over at [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bast way to practice Chinese is talking to native Chinese speaker, but if you don’t have the opportunity, you can try to watch Chinese TV shows.
And Siri is not a good choice.

Comment: So, I shouldn't be using Siri, right? What else should I use to test my Mandarin Chinese then, hm?

Comment: @SteveWoods You can use Siri of course, but it is not the best choice, the best choice is talking to native speakers. You can try an Application called HelloTalk.

Answer (score 1):

Update, I might misunderstand you question, sorry.

Siri's pronunciation of Chinese is a little awkward. It sounds very machine like and not natural at all. Also, some expressions it is using is very uncommon or very literal, which would make you feel strange when listening to it.

---

You are right, it is not quite good a pronunciation in Chinese, there is no official Chinese name of it, however, some people have come up with ideas like

> 思蕊 or 思睿

Comment: So, perhaps something like Google Now can interpret Chinese much better? Thank you for the answer btw.

Comment: 答非所问吧..........

Comment: @user3306356 他的意思是 Siri 在中文里的发音是不是比较别扭还是 Siri 的中文发音好不好？

Comment: 显然答非所问了(づ ●─● )づ

Comment: @TooskyHierot 那就重答吧……

Comment: That's alright. You still gave me knowledge. An answer to my question.

Comment: @SteveWoods Haha, glad it still helps!